# Is casting to boolean always the same as this degenerate if statement?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, casting, equivalent

Consider these two statements:

```
$result = [bool]$SomeObject
$result = if ($SomeObject) { $true } else { $false }
```

These two statements *seem* equivalent, but I am often surprised by PowerShell's quirks.  Normally I'd try to work this kind of thing out from a language specification, but the closest thing to that seems to be stackoverflow.

1. Are the above two statements equivalent for all possible types and values of `$SomeObject`?
2. Is the answer to (1) actually baked into the CLR?  If so, how can I tell that is the case?

Comment: There is, in fact, a [PowerShell language spec](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36389). However, I have not seen one past version 3.0 and we are coming on version 5 soon.

Comment: How would the equivalence of any two statements in another language be "baked into" the CLR?

Comment: Wow. I stand corrected. I wonder why I've never seen that document referenced before.

Comment: @mikez I don't know.  I'm really asking this from a position of ignorance about how the CLR and Powershell work together, so (2) might just be a dumb question.

Comment: FWIW, I tried writing some C# classes with user-defined conversions to boolean and it doesn't look like PowerShell considers user-defined conversions in either case. I suspect there is short list of built-in conversions and they are used for both cases.